# whether drone support trigger build on downstream repository

Tags: continuous-integration, drone.io

Currently I have two repos on github and use drone as the CI. Each of the repos have its own .drone.yum file. There is a dependency between these two repos. One repo is the upstream white the other is the downstream. I want  Drone to support trigger downstream repo after finishing the build on the upstream repo automatically. Whether drone support this transition? How can I achieve it?

Comment: Hi, I think that feature does not exist on Drone, You should achieve that using a plugin, when the upstream repo is building a plugin is called to build the downstream repo.

Comment: Do you mean I need to create a plugin for that? Or is there an existed plugin I can use to achieve that? If yes, could you show me an example of using such plugin?

Comment: @Zhao Yi Could this be of use? https://github.com/drone-plugins/drone-downstream/blob/master/DOCS.md

Comment: yes it is something I need. I will try this one. Thanks.